# Preloading MKMapView in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, mkmapview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make "tab" experience. Each tab has width of screen and user can swipe between each of them. Everything is working just fine, except that on tab with index "3" MKMapView is implemented.

[image]

When user open app, collection view is initialized to index "1", also `cellForIndexAtIndexPath` is called for `IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PageIndentifier, for: indexPath) as! TabCell

    if (indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        cell.SetupNearestView()
        NearestView = cell.nearestView
        NearestView?.Delegate = self
    }

    if (indexPath.item == 1)
    {
        cell.SetupStationsView()
        StationsView = cell.stationsView
        StationsView?.Delegate = self
    }

    if (indexPath.item == 2)
    {
        cell.SetupMapView()
        MapView = cell.stationsMapView
    }

    return cell
}
```

Issue is that UI is blocked for about second when user swipe from 1 -> 2 then collection view triggers `cellForIndexAtIndexPath` is called for `IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)`. I was trying "force" load cell at that index but unfortunatelly, map seems to be initialized just before rendering on screen. Is there any workaround for that?

*edit:*

TabCell.swift

```
class TabCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
var nearestView : NearestView?
var stationsView : StationsView?
var stationsMapView : MapView?

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear, RuntimeResources.Get(color: .VeryDarkBlue).cgColor]
    layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func SetupNearestView()
{
    if (nearestView != nil)
    {
        return
    }

    nearestView = NearestView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    addSubview(nearestView!)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: nearestView!)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: nearestView!)

}

func SetupMapView()
{
    if (stationsMapView != nil)
    {
        return
    }

    stationsMapView = MapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    addSubview(stationsMapView!)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: stationsMapView!)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: stationsMapView!)
}

func SetupStationsView()
{
    if (stationsView != nil)
    {
       return
    }

    stationsView = StationsView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
    addSubview(stationsView!)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: stationsView!)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: stationsView!)
}
}
```

MapView.swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapView: MKMapView, MKMapViewDelegate
{
private let infoViewHeight = CGFloat(500)
private let FocusZoomLevel = 0.01
private let ZoomLevel = 0.04
private let centerOfSzczecin = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.433345, longitude: 14.544139)
private var infoViewTopConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint?

lazy var mainStationView : UIView = {

    let msv = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.infoViewHeight))
    msv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    msv.backgroundColor = RuntimeResources.Get(color: .DarkBlue)
    return msv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self

    // Adding info view
    SetupInfoView()

    // Setting center of map
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(ZoomLevel, ZoomLevel)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerOfSzczecin, span: span)
    setRegion(region, animated: false)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func SetupInfoView()
{
    addSubview(mainStationView)
    infoViewTopConstraint = mainStationView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
    infoViewTopConstraint?.isActive = true
    mainStationView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    mainStationView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    mainStationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: infoViewHeight).isActive = true
}

}
```

Comment: If your UI is blocked then you are doing something wrong here: cell.SetupMapView() , has nothing with preloading to do.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I'm creating new MapView instance and manipulating constraints of this, there is no extra work here. No data loading, no annotations drawing, no cpu intensive or blocking tasks.

Comment: First, you can make it easier and add the code that you call to the question. Second you are calling the function cell.SetupMapView() everytime cellForRowAtItem gets called, do you do any checks to avoid redoing everything everytime your cell gets called?

Comment: I'll post more code in short time. Sure I made enough checks, my issue occurs only once per application run.

Comment: Just added some more source

Comment: are you reusing these views subviews? Or do you use them in a single cell? Also, is this only 1 mapview or are you loading several mapviews?

Comment: I'm using three objects for each cell (there are three), also each of views is initialized only once. I have only one mapview.

Comment: Try my solution in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not reusing the MapView cell.

Try loading your mapView as a variable **outside** of your `UICollectionViewCell` (In your `UIViewController`) and add it as a subView to the cell in [collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc)

and in [collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618006-collectionview?language=objc) you can remove it from the cell.

Simply load all your mapView code outside of your cell and just use the Cell to display the map as a subview that is.

Comment: You were right! Initializing object of map is really CPU intensive, I made this inside initializer of parent ViewController and only added to cell as subview, now working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcin Glad to help :)